# React-router not matching any route on Link or NavLink click (but it works if we do a refresh)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I've spent many hours trying to debug a problem with React-Router-Dom today but with no success, so I'm writing this post. I have no idea what's going on.

Before describing you the problem, here are the versions of the packages used here:

```
React: ^16.6.3
react-dom: ^16.6.3
react-router-dom: ^5.2.0
```

I have a React app with a Root component rendered by `ReactDOM.render`. It renders redux's Provider and a Router for the two basic cases of the app depending on whether the user is connected or not.

Root.tsx:

```
interface Props {
  store: StoreType
}

const Root: FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ store }) => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path="/login" component={Login} exact />
      <Route path="/" component={Dashboard} />
      <Route // this route was just been added to debug my problem
        path="*"
        render={props => {
          console.log(props)
          return <div>Hello</div>
        }}
      />
    </Router>
  </Provider>
)

export default Root
```

The Dashboard is a layout container that renders a sidebar, a topbar and the main section where all my routes are rendered in a `SwitchRoutes` component. It fetches the needed data from an api and displays a loader while doing so.
Here's it's render function.

Dashboard.js:

```
render() {
    const { classes, ...rest } = this.props

    if (!this.state.loader.appReady) {
      return <CustomLoader ready={this.state.loader.dataFetched} />
    }

    if (this.props.users.redirectTo !== null) {
      return <Redirect to={this.props.users.redirectTo} />
    }

    const { zones } = this.props

    return (
      <div className={classes.wrapper}>
        <ErrorBoundary component="Sidebar">
          <Sidebar
            routes={dashboardRoutes(role().shift()).reduce(
              sitesReducer(get(zones, "list").filter(zone => zone.zoneLevel.id === this.firstLevelZone)),
              []
            )}
            logo={logo}
            toggleMenu={this.toggleMenu}
            open={this.state.openedMenu}
            color="red"
            {...rest}
          />
        </ErrorBoundary>

        <div className={classes.mainPanel} ref="mainPanel">
          <TopBar toggleMenu={this.toggleMenu}>{this.topbarContent}</TopBar>

          <div className="spectral__layout-page-name default-font">
            <h5>{this.pageName()}</h5>
          </div>

          <div className={classes.content}>
            <div className={classes.container}>
              {this.state.materialRoutes.length && (
                <ErrorBoundary component="SwitchRoutes">
                  <SwitchRoutes materialRoutes={this.state.materialRoutes} />
                </ErrorBoundary>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

And the SwitchRoutes component:

```
const SwitchRoutes = ({ materialRoutes }) => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      {dashboardRoutes(role().shift()).map(prop => {
        if (prop.redirect) return <Redirect from={prop.path} to={prop.to} key="redirect" />
        if (prop.children && prop.children.length) {
          return prop.children
            .filter(c => c.onSidebar)
            .map(c => {
              return <Route exact={c.exact} path={c.path} component={c.component} key={`route_${c.path}`} />
            })
        }
        if (prop.path.startsWith("/materials")) {
          return (
            <Route
              path="/materials"
              key="route__material_wrapper"
              render={props => <MaterialIndexModule {...props} routes={materialRoutes} />}
            />
          )
        }
        return <Route exact={prop.exact} path={prop.path} component={prop.component} key={`route_${prop.path}`} />
      })}
      <Route component={NotFound} path="*" />
    </Switch>
  )
}
```

This renders locally if I do a refresh, so I know that react-router matches with "/" to render my Dashboard and then the other routes. But when I click on any link to go to another page, the Dashboard then unmounts and I'm just left with the Root component being rendered. Quite confusing.
Each component rendering a Link or a NavLink is exported with react-router-dom's withRouter HOC, and it still fails to render anything.

In case you need more information, here's an extract of the array `dashboardRoutes` I'm mapping over in SwitchRoutes and Sidebar:

```
const dashboardRoutes = role => [
  {
    name: "Home",
    path: "/",
    exact: true,
    component: App,
    onSidebar: false,
    sidebarName: "",
    navbarName: "",
    icon: PinDrop,
  },
  {
    name: "scenarios",
    path: "/scenarios",
    component: Scenarios,
    exact: false,
    onSidebar: true,
    sidebarName: "Scenarios",
    navbarName: "Scenarios",
    icon: PinDrop,
  },
  {
    name: "materials",
    path: "/materials",
    component: Materials,
    onSidebar: true,
    exact: false,
    sidebarName: "Materials",
    navbarName: "Materials",
  }
]
```

As said before, once the app is rendered, any link I click on fails to render the Dashboard and sends me the not-found route I've added in the Root component. When I log the match and location props, here's what is printed:

```
{
  location: {
    hash: ""
    key: "koo33kue"
    pathname: "/materials/rooms/18" // the route I wanted to reach
    search: ""
    state: null
  },
  match: {
    params: {0: "undefined"},
    url: "undefined",
    path: "*",
    isExact: false
  }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using the low-level Router component. You probably want to use the BrowserRouter or MemoryRouter instead.

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';


const Root: FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ store }) => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Route path="/login" component={Login} exact />
      <Route path="/" component={Dashboard} />
      <Route // this route was just been added to debug my problem
        path="*"
        render={props => {
          console.log(props)
          return <div>Hello</div>
        }}
      />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
)

export default Root
```

Comment: Damn, how did I miss that?? Thank you a lot!

Comment: Nice way to find out what is happening. With me, the query string was part of the pathname thus not matching.

Answer (score 0):

I know the problem was solved after switching to BrowserRouter, but just to make sense about the actual problem. This is for those guys who really wanna use the low level Router. The problem is with the history package that you have installed.
Try using the prior versions like 4.7.2 which lets your import default export createHistory from history/createBrowserHistory instead of the latest ones which imports named export createBrowserHistory from history directly.

From what i experienced the latest history lets your change routes only on page refresh and also for navlink or link it doesn't maches any routes just changes the url.

well thats all hope its helps someone.